# Victools JSON schema generator creates two definitions for the same class

Tags: java, jsonschema

Using the JSON schema generator from victools (this generates a JSON schema based on Java classes), I get a strange result if I relate two classes with a common supertype, and `@JsonTypeName` is used.

Please consider the following code:

```
@JsonTypeName("Root")
public class Root {
    private String rootName;
    ... 
    private List<SuperClass1> superclass1 = new ArrayList<SuperClass1>();
    ...
}
```

```
@JsonTypeName("SuperClass1")
@JsonTypeInfo(  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Sub1.class, name = "Sub1"),
@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Sub2.class, name = "Sub2")})
public abstract class SuperClass1 {
    String name;
    int someThingElse;
    
    Root root;

    ...
}
```

```
@JsonTypeName("Sub1")
public class Sub1 extends SuperClass1 {
    String sub1;
    ...
    Sub2 sub2;
    ...
}
```

```
@JsonTypeName("Sub2")
public class Sub2 extends SuperClass1{
    String sub2;
    ...
}
```

generates the following JSON schema:

```
{
  "$schema" : "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions" : {
    "Sub1" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "properties" : {
        "root" : {
          "$ref" : "#"
        },
        "sub1" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "sub2" : {
          "$ref" : "#/definitions/Sub2-2"
        }
      }
    },
    "Sub2-1" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "properties" : {
        "root" : {
          "$ref" : "#"
        },
        "sub2" : {
          "type" : "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "Sub2-2" : {
      "allOf" : [ {
        "$ref" : "#/definitions/Sub2-1"
      }, {
        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
          "type" : {
            "const" : "json_test.Sub2"
          }
        },
        "required" : [ "type" ]
      } ]
    }
  },
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "rootName" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "superclass1" : {
      "type" : "array",
      "items" : {
        "anyOf" : [ {
          "allOf" : [ {
            "$ref" : "#/definitions/Sub1"
          }, {
            "type" : "object",
            "properties" : {
              "type" : {
                "const" : "json_test.Sub1"
              }
            },
            "required" : [ "type" ]
          } ]
        }, {
          "$ref" : "#/definitions/Sub2-2"
        } ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This happens if a property of the `Sub1` class refers to the `Sub2` class, and `@JsonTypeInfo(  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")` is used.

Can someone explain me why it generates `Sub2-1` and `Sub2-2`, and not just `Sub2` in the definitions section?

Thanks,

-- Jaap

Comment: Hi Jaap, since the generator is highly configurable, it’d help if you could share your configuration. But I can answer your question in general.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is due to the inner workings of the schema generator:

- `Sub2-1` represents the “raw” type if you will
- `Sub2-2` represents `Sub2-1` with the additional “type” property added by Jackson

Normally, if `Sub2-1` is only referenced once, it should be inlined into the second schema and therefore allow that second schema to be labelled as just `Sub2`. At least for `Sub1` that appears to be working as intended.

I suggest you provide a full reproducible example as “Issue” on the `victools` GitHub repository and I can take a look, whether this is a bug that can be easily fixed or at least explained by your specific setup.

*Note: I’m the maintainer of that library.*